# Loading huge flatfiles to SQL table is too slow via SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I receive about 8 huge delimited flatfiles to be loaded into an SQL server (2012)table once every week. Total number of rows in all the files would be about 150 million and each file has different number of rows. I have a simple SSIS package which loads data from flatfiles(using foreach container) into a history table. And then a select query runs on this history table to select current weeks data and loads into a staging table.

We ran into problems as history table grew very large(8 billion rows). So I decided to back up the data in history table and truncate. Before truncation the package execution time ranged from 15hrs to 63 hrs in that order.We hoped after truncation it should go back to 15hrs or less.But to my surprise even after 20+ hours the package is still running. The worst part is that it is still loading the history table. Latest count is around 120 million. It still has to load the staging data and it might take just as long.

Neither history table nor staging tables have any indexes, which is why select query on the history table used to take most of the execution time. But loading from all the flatfiles to history table was always under 3 hrs. 
I hope i'm making sense. Can someone help me understand what could be the reason behind this unusual execution time for this week? Thanks.

**Note:** The biggest file(8GB) was read at flatfile source in 3 minutes. So I'm thinking source is not the bottle neck here.

Answer (score 0):

There's *no* good reason, IMHO, why that server should take that long to load that much data.  Are you saying that the process which used to take 3 hours, now takes 60+?  Is it the first (data-load) or the second (history-table) portion that has suddenly become slow?  Or, both at once?

I think the first thing that I would do is to "trust, but verify" that there are no indexes at play here.  The second thing I'd look at is the storage allocation for this tablespace ... is it running out of room, such that the SQL server is having to do a bunch of extra calesthenics to obtain and to maintain storage?  How does this process COMMIT?  After every row?  Can you *prove* that the package definition has not changed in the slightest, recently?

Obviously, "150 million rows" is not a lot of data, these days; neither is 8GB.  If you were "simply" moving those rows into an un-indexed table, "3 hours" would be a generous expectation.  Obviously, the only credible root-cause of this kind of behavior is that the disk-I/O load has increased dramatically, *and* I am healthily suspicious that "excessive COMMITs" might well be part of the cause:  re-writing instead of "lazy-writing," re-reading instead of caching.